# Printing top values of each cluster in DBSCAN

Tags: python, k-means, dbscan

I am implementing a code for text clustering in python using k means and DBSCAN. The K Means code is written as below:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    num_clusters = 5
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
    %time km.fit(tfidf_matrix)
    clusters = km.labels_.tolist()

    import pandas as pd
    films = { 'title': titles, 'rank': ranks, 'synopsis': synopses, 'cluster': clusters, 'genre': genres }
    frame = pd.DataFrame(films, index = [clusters] , columns = ['rank', 'title', 'cluster', 'genre'])


    print("Top terms per cluster:")
    print()
    order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
    for i in range(num_clusters):
        print("Cluster %d words:" % i, end='')
        for ind in order_centroids[i, :6]:
            print(' %s' % vocab_frame.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0].encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), end=',')
        print()
        print()
        print("Cluster %d titles:" % i, end='')
        for title in frame.loc[i]['title'].values.tolist():
            print(' %s,' % title, end='')
        print()
```

The output is as desired:

Cluster 0 words: b'soldiers', b'killed', b'army', b'camps', b'war', b'command',

Cluster 1 words: b'police', b'killed', b'car', b'murders', b'apartments', b'asks',
...

Now, when running the same code with DBSCAN, What I could do is:

```
    from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN 
    DBS_clf = DBSCAN(eps=.85, min_samples=1.5)
    DBS_clf.fit(tfidf_matrix)
    DBS_clusters = DBS_clf.labels_.tolist()
```

but I could not get the top terms printed (for indices 0 and above as -1 is for noise) as I could find no alternate for cluster_centers_ for DBSCAN, which is of course logical as DBSCAN has a very different working. Please guide as I am scratching my head with no understanding of what I should do. I am not very good at Python.